# WPF XAML save scrollable control to PDF with multiple pages

Tags: wpf, xaml, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm having quite an issue making this work, as I don't know what would be the best approach for this.

What I have is a View in which I have a ScrollViewer. In that ScrollViewer I have a created a sort of report that I want to eventually print on a printer, but also save to PDF. The report consists of some static items, but I also have a ListView that has dinamicaly generated content.

I managed to create a PDF using the  with all contents on it but this results in a page that is not of the A4 format. I understand this is because my content is inside a  witin a single . I know that I can manually create a new page by using another , but I can't do this, because a page content can change at runtime (due to the ListView).

How can I save my scrollable control to a PDF and have it manually split to A4 pages if the content is too long? Preferably I would also like to split it so that no element is cut between pages (Like a textbox for example).

I also tried this with FlowDocumentPageViewer, but I'm having the same issue of how to automaticaly split to pages when content is too large.

I also tried it with PdfSharp library, but I only managed to make it print items that are currently visible on the main View.